# How to move folders in github repo from sub-folder to parent folder and delete the now empty sub-folder?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am taking an online course, and my repository for that course is as follows -

- Course Repo

  - Course Term 1

    - Project 1
    - Project 2
    - Project 3

I initially planned to add additional Terms under the same parent folder/repo of "Course Name". Instead, I decided to have different repos for different Terms. So now I want the above to be structured like -

- Course Term 1 Repo

  - Project 1
  - Project 2
  - Project 3

What's the best way to do the above? Should I just cut-paste the Project folders under the now renamed "Course Name Term 1" folder, and then delete the now empty "Course Term 1" folder and the commit and push? Or is there a better (elegant) way to do this via git? I don't want to lose commit history or anything that "breaks anything" for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to extract a subfolder ("`Course Term 1` ") of your current repo ("`Course Repo` ") as its own repo ("`Course Term 1 Repo`")

See:

- "[Splitting a subfolder out into a new repository](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/)", or
- "[Split a repository in two](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/split-a-repository-in-two-313464964.html)"

That way, you keep the full history of each subfolder you extract as a repo.

---

> what if I don't want the subfolder to be a new repo?

- if "Course Term 1" is a repo, then my answer stands.
- If "Course Term 1" is just a folder part of a repo, then the right way to move subfolder while keeping the history is with [`git mv`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv).

Comment: Thank you! But what if I don't want the subfolder to be a new repo? I just want to move them out from the "Course Term 1" folder. [Asking since this was the original question]

Comment: @sj22 iThen see my revised answer.

Comment: Ohh ok. Interesting. Thanks :)